# Import nested documents with mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, database, nosql

I'm trying to import something like the following:

```
{
    "RECORDS": [
        {"very much data": "with very much information"},
        {"very much data": "with very much information"},
        {"very much data": "with very much information"},
        {"very much data": "with very much information"},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

The Problem is that I got a sql database export that should be transferred into MongoDB. It's about 3.3GB, so I can't open it, correct the mistakes at beginning and end and save it. Is there a way to select the array "RECORDS" when calling mongoimport?

Comment: Mongo can read files that big. From what i see your problem is SQL export file. It's not valid mongoimport format. So i suggest you to make code that generates correct mongo import file or read file and save documents one by one. Read this docs. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/ Hope this helps.